# ext2 or ext3 filesystem with the most available space

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, filesystems, ext3, ext2

First of all, security is important so I want to use a reasonable size of inode backups and things like that, whatever those mean...

I want to use ext2 or ext3 for a common partition between Win7 and Ubuntu (with [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/)).

My problem is, that I created a 850 gig ext2 partition and GParted says:

```
Size: 853.15 GiB
Used:  13.46 GiB
```

This is NOT the 5% space reserved to the root user (it would be more than 40gigs). And of course I tried `tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda4`. **Is it normal that 13 gig is lost just for the filesystem?**

All help is appreciated.

Some details if you need it:

```
# partition table of /dev/sda
unit: sectors

/dev/sda1 : start=     2048, size=   389120, Id=83, bootable
/dev/sda2 : start=   393214, size= 82028546, Id= 5
/dev/sda3 : start= 82429515, size= 81915435, Id= 7
/dev/sda4 : start=164345856, size=1789177856, Id=83
/dev/sda5 : start=   393216, size= 78123008, Id=83
/dev/sda6 : start= 78518272, size=  3903488, Id=82
```

`df` says:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5             38445384   5101796  31390516  14% /
none                   2021640       660   2020980   1% /dev
none                   2029348      1512   2027836   1% /dev/shm
none                   2029348       348   2029000   1% /var/run
none                   2029348         0   2029348   0% /var/lock
/dev/sda1               182331     22620    149983  14% /boot
/dev/sda4            880550492     73744 880476748   1% /media/334cb5f6-2f18-4193-b2c8-99bd42cd6f01
```

`tune2fs -l /dev/sda4` says:

```
tune2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
Filesystem volume name:   
Last mounted on:          
Filesystem UUID:          334cb5f6-2f18-4193-b2c8-99bd42cd6f01
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype sparse_super large_file
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    (none)
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              55918592
Block count:              223647232
Reserved block count:     0
Free blocks:              220119187
Free inodes:              55918581
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      970
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Filesystem created:       Sat May 21 10:35:15 2011
Last mount time:          n/a
Last write time:          Sat May 21 11:21:55 2011
Mount count:              8
Maximum mount count:      20
Last checked:             Sat May 21 10:35:15 2011
Check interval:           15552000 (6 months)
Next check after:         Thu Nov 17 09:35:15 2011
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      7ba9b270-1cc8-4622-b25c-768497678f99
```

`cat /etc/mke2fs.conf` says:

```
[defaults]
    base_features = sparse_super,filetype,resize_inode,dir_index,ext_attr
    blocksize = 4096
    inode_size = 256
    inode_ratio = 16384

[fs_types]
    ext3 = {
        features = has_journal
    }
    ext4 = {
        features = has_journal,extent,huge_file,flex_bg,uninit_bg,dir_nlink,extra_isize
        inode_size = 256
    }
    ext4dev = {
        features = has_journal,extent,huge_file,flex_bg,uninit_bg,dir_nlink,extra_isize
        inode_size = 256
        options = test_fs=1
    }
    small = {
        blocksize = 1024
        inode_size = 128
        inode_ratio = 4096
    }
    floppy = {
        blocksize = 1024
        inode_size = 128
        inode_ratio = 8192
    }
    news = {
        inode_ratio = 4096
    }
    largefile = {
        inode_ratio = 1048576
        blocksize = -1
    }
    largefile4 = {
        inode_ratio = 4194304
        blocksize = -1
    }
    hurd = {
         blocksize = 4096
         inode_size = 128
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading, and then reading a bit more I came to the conclusion that the inodes are taking up this tremendous amount of space.

You can confirm this with the tune2fs output by multiplying the following values:

```
Inode count:              55918592
Inode size:               256
```

... and this will indeed give you the missing 13 gigs (14 315 159 552).

In the make2fs.conf file you can see the following default: `inode_ratio = 16384`. Multiplying this with the number of inodes gives the full partition size (916 170 211 328), so this is exactly what it seems. The number of inodes is calculated by `partition size / inode_ratio`.

As I read shrinking the inode size is not recommended, but the `inode_ratio` itself will give you a wide space to move. The `largefile` preset creates an inode for every 1 MByte.

I did not went that far (no small operating-system-files will be stored on this partition, but downloads and sometimes source code will), so I ended up with a moderated **128000**. It does not have to be a power of 2, inodes are not a 1-1 mirror of the HD data (like FAT16), they are used more dynamically.

This (combined with `-m 0` of course) only took 2 gigs out of my big partition. Which is something I can live with.

```
mkfs.ext3 -i 128000 -m 0 /dev/sda4
```

This gave me 9 million inodes (which limits the maximum number of files and dirs too, that can be stored on the HD). But as I said earlier, no OS will be installed on it, and cosidering the linux kernel source contains around 25 000 files, the step from the earlier 55 mill to 9 mill inodes seems to be a good tradeoff.

**Disclaimer:**

You **must be careful** about setting up the inode_ratio, as your filesystem will bear this forever. You can not add inodes to (an ext2 or ext3) partition afterwards without reformatting it.

It is also **not** possible to just shrink the partition and create a new one on the free space if you run out of inodes because shrinking the partion would proportinally decrease inodes, so you can not do it with only a few inodes free.

Comment: Yes, you found it right. Regular format of that partition allows to create **55 millions** of files and directories, and the housekeeping for that will take 13 gigs of the raw partition capacity. 13 gigs seem a lot, but it is only 1.5% of the total. 1.5% for all that versatility, is it a good compromise? You can reduce the inode ratio, it's your storage. Just be quite sure that the **average** file size in bytes will be **higher** that the inode ratio number, see http://serverfault.com/a/523210 for details.